# Unable to retrieve records from Firebase in Xamarin c#

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin

In my app, I have connected with the Firebase and trying to populate the listview, but on the start, I don't see any records populated.  It just shows a blank page without anything populated in the list views.

This is my firebasehelper.cs

```
{
class FirebaseHelper
{
    FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://mylimo-b2029.firebaseio.com/");


    public async Task<List<users>> GetAllUsers()
    {

        try
        {
          return (await firebase
         .Child("Users")
         .OnceAsync<users>()).Select(item => new users
         {
             //,

             first_name = item.Object.first_name,
             last_name = item.Object.last_name,
             password = item.Object.password,
             user_id = item.Object.user_id,
         }).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("GetUsers  Additional information..." + ex, ex);
        }
    }    


    public async Task<users> GetUsers(string usr_id)
    {
        try
        {
            var allUsers = await GetAllUsers();
            await firebase
              .Child("users")
              .OnceAsync<users>();
            return allUsers.Where(a => a.user_id == usr_id).FirstOrDefault();
        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("GetUsers  Additional information..." + ex, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    FirebaseHelper firebaseHelper = new FirebaseHelper();
    public MainPage()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("InitializeComponent  Additional information..." + ex, ex);
        }
    }

    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            var allUsers = await firebaseHelper.GetAllUsers();
            lstPersons.ItemsSource = allUsers;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("OnAppearing  Additional information..." + ex, ex);
        }




    }
```

At the start of the app, it will just show a blank list view control without any records,

.

My firebase database is as below][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP11N.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is normal.But your may less some steps.

Please refer to following ways to use Firebase database.

First of all, Please open the firebase database console, set the read/write auth rule to null like following screenshot.

[image]

Then create a module `user`.

```
public class User
{
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }

    public string password { get; set; }

    public int userid { get; set; }
}
```

There is my firebasehelper.

```
public class Firebasehelper
{
    FirebaseClient firebase;

    public Firebasehelper()
    {
        firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://fir-databasedemo-62a72.firebaseio.com/");
    }
   
    public async Task AddUser(int userid, string first_name, string last_name, string password)
    {
        await firebase
          .Child("Users")
          .PostAsync(new User() { userid = userid, first_name = first_name, last_name= last_name, password= password });
    }

    public async Task<List<User>> GetAllUsers()
    {
        return (await firebase
          .Child("Users")
          .OnceAsync<User>()).Select(item => new User
          {

              userid = item.Object.userid,
              first_name = item.Object.first_name,
              last_name = item.Object.last_name,
              password = item.Object.password
          }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Please do not create records in firebase directly.

We should add these records by code. After adding these records successfully, you can see these records in firebase console.

[image]

Use with following code.

```
  private async void BtnAdd_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        // AddUser(int userid, string first_name, string last_name, string password)
        await firebaseHelper.AddUser(Convert.ToInt32(1), "Jon","hard","123.com");
        await firebaseHelper.AddUser(Convert.ToInt32(1), "Leon", "esay", "1234.com");
        await firebaseHelper.AddUser(Convert.ToInt32(1), "Rebecca", "middlue", "12345.com");
        await DisplayAlert("Success", "Person Added Successfully", "OK");
       var allPersons = await firebaseHelper.GetAllUsers();
       lstPersons.ItemsSource = allPersons;
    }
```

There is my `MainPage.xaml`.

```
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RetrieveRecordDemo"
         x:Class="RetrieveRecordDemo.MainPage">
  <StackLayout>
    <Button x:Name="BtnAdd" Text="add" />

    <ListView x:Name="lstPersons">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>

                        <Label Text="{Binding first_name}"  > 
                 </Label>
                        <Label Text="{Binding last_name}" > 
                 </Label>
                     
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xml.cs

```
   public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    Firebasehelper firebaseHelper;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        firebaseHelper = new Firebasehelper();

        BtnAdd.Clicked += BtnAdd_Clicked;
    }

    private async void BtnAdd_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // AddUser(int userid, string first_name, string last_name, string password)
        await firebaseHelper.AddUser(Convert.ToInt32(1), "Jon","hard","123.com");
        await firebaseHelper.AddUser(Convert.ToInt32(1), "Leon", "esay", "1234.com");
        await firebaseHelper.AddUser(Convert.ToInt32(1), "Rebecca", "middlue", "12345.com");
        await DisplayAlert("Success", "Person Added Successfully", "OK");
       var allPersons = await firebaseHelper.GetAllUsers();
       lstPersons.ItemsSource = allPersons;
    }

    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {

        base.OnAppearing();


        try
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            var allUsers = await firebaseHelper.GetAllUsers();
            lstPersons.ItemsSource = allUsers;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("OnAppearing  Additional information..." + ex, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

There is running screenshot.

[image]

There is my demo: https://github.com/851265601/RetrieveRecordDemo

There is a helpful article for CRUD in firebase database.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-working-with-firebase-realtime-database-crud-operations/